# Add 1Password extensions support to the SE iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, ios-app

Please implement the URL scheme to call 1Password for password lookups on the iOS app.

http://blog.agilebits.com/2013/01/24/developers-heres-how-to-add-a-little-1password-to-your-ios-apps/

> a URL scheme for switching to 1Password to search item titles for a custom term, usually a service name like “twitter” or “evernote”. This speeds up the process for the user so they can copy something like their password and get back to your app

That will ease sign up speed using long, complicated or unmemorable passwords for many users of both apps. In the two years since the above blog was published there are now updated instructions for implementation and code on github:

- https://agilebits.com/onepassword/devoutreach
- https://github.com/AgileBits/onepassword-app-extension

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but isn't this kind of the point to the OpenID protocol

Comment: @psubsee2003 I don't understand your comment. Integration with 1Password would add a tap target that passes the OpenID URL to the other app and surface any accounts stored (user name and password) that match the OpenID landing point. So, this would enhance/augment the use of OpenID, not replace it.

Comment: That's why you need to include more detail in feature requests.  Not everyone knows these things.  And that explanation to the question is beneficial to getting features accepted :)

Comment: Would love to see the implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari and 1Password now work well enough that for most things, I don’t use the app and haven’t for years. No worries if this app isn’t in development. Times move on.

Answer (score 4):

We discussed this briefly and while nobody was opposed to doing this, really, it just isn't very high on the list.  We still have plenty of bugs coming in that are crashing issues, and we still have a lot of *features* to implement before we will be ready for the app store.  It's not a bad idea, we just aren't going to get to it soon.

Comment: I would probably make the same decision on my 1.0 depending on how many developers I had.