# Could the iOS app for SE have a setting to use 1Password browser for links? It has that option for Chrome already

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I like using the 1Password browser, so it would be nice if Stack Overflow for iOS had a setting specifying what browser to use. Right now it opens Chrome.

edit: 1Password does has a published URL scheme already: 
ophttp:// or ophttps://

https://blog.agilebits.com/2013/01/24/developers-heres-how-to-add-a-little-1password-to-your-ios-apps/

Scroll down to "Open URLs externally, set 1Password as the default external browser"

edit2: I now see this in related posts. So this is a duplicate from 2014. [Add 1Password extensions support to the SE iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220983/add-1password-support-to-the-ios-app)

Comment: If it would open Chrome, you could use the 1password extension as described [here](http://9to5mac.com/2015/04/16/chrome-ios-widget-extensions/).

Comment: Thank you for link to 1password Chrome extension instructions, @Glorfindel, I was unaware. It's a few more clicks then with using 1password browser directly, but better than copying url from chrome and opening 1password browser, then pasting.

Comment: Yes - this is exactly the feature I requested and e developers deferred when the app was in beta test. Maybe the development is such that this can be considered now?

Answer (score 3):

There's a switch in the Stack Exchange app settings to "Use Chrome (if installed)".

This is possible because Google has published [a URL scheme for Chrome](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1). They even provide a [component that iOS apps can include](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/ios/links) to make opening links in Chrome easier.

The OS doesn't provide the capability to open links in an arbitrary app: importantly, **the browser you'd like to use must support it before SE** can add this feature.

Comment: Thank you. I have asked 1Password via Twitter to provide an answer here. I have also Googled this myself and found that 1Password does has a published URL scheme already. https://blog.agilebits.com/2013/01/24/developers-heres-how-to-add-a-little-1password-to-your-ios-apps/  Scroll down to "Open URLs externally, set 1Password as the default external browser"

Comment: Should I accept this answer, or wait until Stack Exchange adds an option to open 1Password browser? My first Stack Exchange app feature request.

Comment: It's up to you; it probably makes more sense to wait. My answer doesn't really resolve the issue. It is possible to change the accepted answer later, though, if you need to.

Comment: 1password responded to me on Twitter that they can't even post here because they don't have enough reputation (I think he tried when my post was scored -1). Very sad in my opinion. Anyway the link I provided is all you need to implement this. "Basically, prepend op in front of http and https and it'll open in 1Password." -1Password developer on Twitter.

Comment: @Andy true, this is what they see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/mK6yu.png.

Comment: Disallowing new users from posting here [was supposed to be temporary](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/278688/users-with-1-rep-cant-view-any-questions-here-on-mse/278689#278689), @Andy. Apparently the problem that led to it has not abated.